# How to make labels for a 2-D figure with Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Goal: obtain the figure format like this one, Figure C in Fig.5.[enter link description here](http://dna.caltech.edu/Papers/DNA_for_CRNs_2010_PNAS.pdf)

Assume: we draw Sin[x] with the range from 0 to 2Pi.

```
Plot[Sin[2 x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, AxesLabel -> {Style["time (hr)", 20], Style["Concentration (nM)", 20]},AxesStyle -> Directive[Thick, FontSize -> 15]]
```

Question: How to make labels for both x and y axes without adding annoying frames?

What's more:

```
Plot[Sin[2 x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, AxesLabel -> {Style["hr", 20], Style["nM", 20]},AxesStyle -> Directive[Thick, FontSize -> 20]]
```

Codes like this couldn't obtain the similar format in A of Fig.6, especially for "hr" and "nM".

Please do me a favour!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Labeled[
 Plot[Sin[2 x], {x, 0, 2 Pi},
  AxesStyle -> Directive[Thick, FontSize -> 15]],
 {Style["time (hr)", 20, FontFamily -> "Arial", Darker@Gray],
  Rotate[
   Style["Concentration (nM)", 20, FontFamily -> "Arial", Darker@Gray],
   90 Degree]},
 {Bottom, Left}]
```

[image]

```
Labeled[
 Plot[Sin[2 x], {x, 0, 2 Pi},
  AxesLabel -> {Style["\nhr", 20]},
  AxesStyle -> Directive[Thick, FontSize -> 20]],
 {Style["nM", 20, FontFamily -> "Arial", Darker@Gray]},
 {{Left, Top}}]
```

[image]

***Re. problem exporting PNG***

No visible problem:-

[image]

Comment: Your method is actually great! But when I save it as png, the picture doesn't cover the labels we add. Could you solve this problem? Really looking forward to your answer.

Comment: Hi, I'm not seeing a problem.  Perhaps you are saving it in a different way from the example I have just added.

Comment: Really appreciate! Usually, I just right-clik (hope correctly express) the elected figure, then choose “save as png”. But now I get a new skill! Thanks again, Chris!